# code not working when setTimeout is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkitspeechrecognition

I am trying to write  a code that could use voice input and based on input can migrate to another page.
My code is not waiting when timeout is used and without timeout,the code is not waiting for input.
**HTML Page:**

```
<script src="Content/SpeechRecognisation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Content/SpeechUtterance.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Content/LoginScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Content/Additional.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Login Screen</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body onload="Typer()"></body>
```

**Javascript code** in Js file:

```
function LoginPageSpeech() {
    pageName = 'LoginPage';
    controlPointer = "1";
    var CPR_No = final_transcript;
    $("#txtCPRNo").val(final_transcript);
    var pageDetail = "Entered CPR Number is " + final_transcript;
    CustomerResponse = final_transcript;
    speak(pageDetail);
    setTimeout(function(){},4000);
    speak("if details are correct ,please say yes else say no after beep");
    setTimeout(function () { SoundMake(); }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function() {startDictation(event);},3000);
    setTimeout(function() { },4000);
    if (final_transcript == "YES") {
        setTimeout(AuthenticationMsg,7000);
    }
    else
    {
//        setTimeout(function () { speak("Sorry.Please repeat again after beep"); }, 4000);
//        setTimeout(function () { SoundMake(); }, 3000);
//        setTimeout(function () { startDictation(event); }, 3000);
//        
//        LoginPageSpeech();
    }
}


function Typer() {
    pageName = "LoginPage";
    speak('Welcome ,Please Speak your CPR Number after a beep');

    setTimeout(function () { SoundMake(); }, 4000);
    timeOutValue = 9000;
    setTimeout(function () { startDictation(event); }, 4000);

}
function SoundMake() {
    var snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,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");
    snd.play();
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] instead of just pasting non functional code into a question. Use the `<>` button in the editor. You need to go to the documentation and see how to speak and wait for input

Comment: Sure.i removed the un-necessary part

Comment: do you get any errors in console?>

Comment: @vish1990 can you make a demo of it on jsfiddle.net or your development URL. Understanding your code in this way is quite tough. 
Also a thought you're using a lot of `setTimeount` have you considered clearing them if not being used 2nd time by `clearTimeout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `setTimeout` in the wrong way. For instance, look at this part:

```
setTimeout(function(){},4000);
speak("if details are correct ,please say yes else say no after beep");
setTimeout(function () { SoundMake(); }, 4000);
setTimeout(function() {startDictation(event);},3000);
setTimeout(function() { },4000);
```

It seems like you expect the execution to halt for 4 seconds on the first line, and only then continue with the second. But that is not true. The only thing that gets delayed is the function you pass as argument to `setTimeout`: it will be called later. But the engine will immediately continue with the next statement. In fact, none of the functions you pass to `setTimeout` *can* execute before all the remaining code has been executed.

So... now you can see the first line of the block above is quite useless. It says: *"do nothing 4 seconds from now, and now continue with the next statement"*.

### How to fix

There are several ways, some ugly, some nice, some in between:

#### 1. Cumulate the time to delay

Knowing that all your `setTimeout` calls execute at practically the same time, specify a delay that also counts for the previous delays:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    speak("if details are correct, please say yes else say no after beep");
},4000);
setTimeout(function () { SoundMake(); }, 4000+4000);
setTimeout(function() {startDictation(event);},4000+4000+3000);
setTimeout(function() { 
    // ...etc
},4000+4000+3000+4000);
```

The downsides are:

- When you change your mind on one delay you need to adapt it at several places. You could counter this by using a variable, which you increase with the next delay.
- When one of the scheduled actions takes a lot of time (or the browser gets busy with other stuff), the interval between actions might get a lot smaller than expected.

#### 2. Nest the callbacks

Here you put the next actions inside the previous callback provided to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    speak("if details are correct, please say yes else say no after beep");
    setTimeout(function () { 
        SoundMake();
        setTimeout(function() {
            startDictation(event);
            setTimeout(function() { 
                // ...etc
            }, 4000);
        }, 3000);
    }, 4000);
}, 4000);
```

The downside is:

- The so-called ["callback hell"](http://callbackhell.com/): your code can get very deeply nested, and in extreme cases your editor might show mostly white space, with your code only becoming visible if you scroll to the right. This is not practical.

#### 3. Recursion

Here you keep invoking the same function which you call again when the next timer ticks:

```
(function loop(i) {
    var delay = 300;
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
        // Do nothing, just launch the setTimeout
        break;
    case 1:
        speak("if details are correct, please say yes else say no after beep");
        break;
    case 2: 
        SoundMake();
        delay = 300;
        break;
    case 3:
        startDictation(event);
        break;
    default:
        // etc...
        return; // start no more timeout
    }
    setTimeout(loop.bind(null, i+1), delay); 
})(0); // start with 0
```

The downside is:

- The `switch` statement is a quite verbose. You could alternatively create an array of objects, where each object has the code to execute as a function property, and the delay as another property. Then you could just index that in the `loop` body.

### 4. Promises

Since ES6 there is a `Promise` object, which many programmers would advise using for this purpose, myself included:

```
// Utility to get a promise object that resolves after a given delay
function promiseDelay(delay) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

promiseDelay(400)
.then(function() {
    speak("if details are correct ,please say yes else say no after beep");
    return promiseDelay(4000);
}).then(function () { 
    SoundMake();
    return promiseDelay(3000);
}).then(function () {
    startDictation(event);
    return promiseDelay(4000);
}).then(function () {
    // etc...
});
```

This code is quite clean and lean.

### Remarks

Note that the above tackles just part of your code. You have the same issues in the *Typer* function. But the principle is the same. Take your preferred solution and apply it throughout.